# Xamarin Forms label click Command binding inside a ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want label click Command binding inside a ListView, In ListView, I have a label. When click that label go to another page.

I tried this, but not working fine. Any other solution?

```
<Label Text="Message"  FontSize="12" Grid.Column="3"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference newsfeedlist}, Path=BindingContext}"  Command="{Binding MessageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}"/>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

A List view has its own bindingContext so the best is to referance the page then the command e.g.

1. First Give your page a name

   ```
    <ContentPage 
        ....
        x:Name="FooPage" 
        Title="Foo">
   ```
2. Then in your list

   ```
            <ListView x:Name="EmployeeListData"  ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}">
                   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <ViewCell>
                               <StackLayout Padding="5"><Label Text="Click Me">
                                   <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                       <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EmployeeActions, Source={x:Reference FooPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                   </Label.GestureRecognizers> </Label>
                               </StackLayout>
                           </ViewCell>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
               </ListView>
   ```
3. Here is the secret source

   **Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EmployeeActions, Source={x:Reference FooPage}}"**